# Why does System.out.println( "\t" + scanner.next() ); give error?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, println

```
sectionScan = new Scanner(wholeLine);
sectionScan.useDelimiter(",");

//Print each part of bat code
while (sectionScan.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println("\t" + sectionScan.next());
    score = sectionScan.next();

    if ("h".equals(score))
        hit++;
    else if ("o".equals(score))
        out++;
    else if ("w".equals(score))
        walk++;
    else if ("s".equals(score))
        sacrifice++;  
}
```

I am running the above code to scan line like this:
`Willy Wonk,o,o,h,o,o,o,o,h,w,o,o,o,o,s,h,o,h`

but it causes error unless I take out the `System.out.println();`

It's from one of my homework, it doesn't require me to have that error line, but I am just curious as to what cause it and how should I fix it?

Comment: It might be easier to help you, if you tell what error you receive. A message perhaps?

Comment: `String#split(String)` seems more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when ever you use `sectionScan.next();` , it will read the next one ,

you could get the temp String like this:

```
String temp=sectionScan.next();
```

and you could do what ever you want to do with that temp

another solution is that to use `split` method like this :

```
String []score=wholeLine.split(",");
```

so you have an array that splited by `,` so you can iterate trough that array like this:

```
for(String str:score){
        //do what ever you want to do with str
    }
```

Comment: ah I see!  Thanks for everyone who helps me ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You are consuming the next element in your println.

```
System.out.println("\t" + sectionScan.next());
```

Instead store the next() value once and reuse it.

```
score = sectionScan.next();
System.out.println("\t" + score);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the `println` you are actually invoking the `next` method twice, but you only check once, in the while condition, if there are elements left. So, per iteration you are retrieving two elements. Eventually, when there is only one element left, you get an exception in your second attempt to invoke the method `next`.

You should invoke the `next` method only once and cache the value in a variable, which you ca later use for any other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to

```
score = sectionScan.next();
System.out.println("\t" + score);
```

You are calling sectionscan.next() twice for every one time you check sectionscan.hasNext() which means you will eventually end up calling .next() when there is no next element.